# How do I determine the cartesian coordinates of the end effector if I know the joint angles?

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the SRDF file which gives the joint angles of the robot for the different poses (using Moveit).
Now in order to do a pick and place task, I need to give the cartesian coordinates of the object in the frame of the robot. So, I moved my robot using Moveit to a position such that the end effector can grasp the object, so that I have the joint angles of the robot for performing the grasp. But, I need the position of the end effector with respect to the robot, when the robot is in that position. How do I determine that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298027/how-do-i-determine-the-cartesian-coordinates-of-the-end-effector-if-i-know-the-joint-angles?/) by [DebasmitaGhose](https://answers.ros.org/users/36567/debasmitaghose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-07-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way is to use `tf_echo`:

```
rosrun tf tf_echo <your_base_link> <your_gripper_frame>
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2018-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2